# Accept variables from the command line to search through log files in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I have an assignment that goes as follows:

```
1. Create a batch file that does the following:
    - Accepts from the command line the following variables:
    - Year (four digit number) of log files that they want to archive
    - Month (two-digit number) of log files that they want to archive
    - Does not display any of the commands to the screen
    - Display just the files names of all of the files in the directory and subdirectories that have the archive attribute turned on in a “wide” display on the screen.
    - Display the message “Beginning archive utility at” and then display the current date and time.
    - Create a subdirectory called archive. If this directory already exists, do not report out an error message.
    - If there are files that correspond to the month and year:
         - Create a subdirectory in the archive directory that corresponds to the month and year entered (six digit number using the format yyyymm)
         -  Move all files with a file name that begins with the corresponding month and year entered (six digit number using the format yyyymm)
        -  If there are not any files that correspond to the month and year entered
         - Returns an error message to explain what happened and the type of input that was expected
          - Turn off the archive attribute of only the files that have been moved.
         - Display just the files names of all of the files in the directory and subdirectories that have the archive attribute turned off.
```

I am not fully understanding what is meant by this, I have googled for help but he points me to the resource https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html. I have tried stack overflow articles for this as well and I am not understanding how to accept the "varibles from the command line" Is it that I have to do a set /p %%? but then how do I pass that through to search the files that are in the folder that have those log files in them?

Comment: Without seeing the entire question/task, our solutions may not be relevant. Are you supposed to be running a batch file from the command prompt, sending two arguments to it `YYYY` and `MM` or is your batch file supposed to ask the end user for each of these two arguments to be typed in, then use what was typed. _(From the page you were pointed to, I'm assuming the former.)_ Also, some sort of indication of what exactly the filenames you're searching for look like and where would assist us.

Comment: The batch file is suspossed to ask the end user for each of the arguments and then use what was typed to search a folder full of log files that have different dates. It also says that no command lines should be displayed to the screen which I assume just means @echo off. I can add the whole thing to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
If %1Err==Err Goto InputError
If %2Err==Err Goto InputError

cls
dir /w /aa
pause
echo Beginning archive utility at
date /t
time /t
REM Create a subdirectory called archive. If this directory already exists, do not report out an error message. 
If not exist archive md archive
cd archive

REM Create a subdirectory in the archive directory that corresponds to the month and year entered (six digit number using the format yyyymm) 
If not exist %1%2 md %1%2
cd ..

REM Move all files with a file name that begins with the corresponding month and year entered (six digit number using the format yyyymm)
If not exist %1%2* Goto NoFiles
move %1%2* archive\%1%2\

REM Turn off the archive attribute of only the files that have been moved.
attrib -A archive\%1%2\*

DIR /S /A-A

Goto TheEnd

:NoFiles
echo There are not files that begin with %1%2
Goto TheEnd


:InputError
echo when running this command please include a four digit year and a two digit month (Ex: COMMAND 2010 12).
Goto TheEnd

:TheEnd
Echo On
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer to cover the first `8` lines of your posted item `1.` *with some artistic license*:

```bat
@Echo Off

Rem Accept from the command line a four digit year and a two digit month.

:AskYear
Rem Clear the console.
ClS
Rem Undefine any existing variable named YYYY.
Set "YYYY="
Rem Ask the user to input a year between 1970 and 2019.
Set /P "YYYY=Please enter a four digit year e.g. 2016 >"
Rem Return to ask again if the user did not enter a four digit year between 1970 and 2019.
Echo "%YYYY%"|FindStr /R "^\"19[7-9][0-9]\"$ ^\"20[0-1][0-9]\"$">NUL||GoTo AskYear

:AskMonth
Rem Clear the console.
ClS
Rem Undefine any existing variable named MM.
Set "MM="
Rem Ask the user to input a two digit month. 
Set /P "MM=Please enter a two digit month e.g. 05 >"
Rem Return to ask again if the user did not enter a two digit month.
Echo "%MM%"|FindStr /R "^\"0[1-9]\"$ ^\"1[0-2]\"$">NUL||GoTo AskMonth

Rem Display all files with archive attibute in wide format. 
Dir /A-DA/W 2>NUL|FindStr /VBC:" "

Rem Display message followed by current date and time.
Echo(&Echo Beginning archive utility at %TIME% on %DATE%&Echo(

Rem Create subdirectory without error messages.
MD "archive" 2>NUL
```

I hope that it's enough for you to help understand the requirements to that point. From there you will be required to determine `if` any files `exist` beginning with `%YYYY%%MM%` and if so proceed from line `10` of item `1.`

*Please feel free to modify the sentencing or remove the `Rem`arks as necessary.*

Comment: This works thank you, the professor provided a zip file of "logs" with thier names as dates i.e 20180122.txt, so I will tweak this to work with archiving those logs and they will redirect back into the folder. Thank you!